# css issue background coming as black

Tags: css

in the image attached some portion is coming with background as black and i am not able to figure out why.

I know i am asking something which is not very descriptive but please if someone can throw some pointers that will help

thanks

[image]

Css below (this is what i got from firebug when i focused the black background element)

```
.curResults .tableTopControls {
    display: block;
    height: 30px;
    line-height: 30px;
    margin: 0 0 5px;
    width: 100%;
}

.tableTopControls {
    font-size: 11px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

html, body, div, span, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre, a, em, img, small, strong, b, u, i, center, ol, ul, li, fieldset, form, label, table, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td {
    border: 0 none;
    font-size: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}

Inherited fromdiv.dataTables_wrapper
html, body, div, span, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre, a, em, img, small, strong, b, u, i, center, ol, ul, li, fieldset, form, label, table, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td {
    font-size: 100%;
}

Inherited fromdiv.table
html, body, div, span, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre, a, em, img, small, strong, b, u, i, center, ol, ul, li, fieldset, form, label, table, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td {
    font-size: 100%;
}

Inherited fromdiv#mainSection_merchandizerContentSection_rsPromotions_recordSetContainer.panel
html, body, div, span, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre, a, em, img, small, strong, b, u, i, center, ol, ul, li, fieldset, form, label, table, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td {
    font-size: 100%;
}

Inherited fromdiv.panel
html, body, div, span, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre, a, em, img, small, strong, b, u, i, center, ol, ul, li, fieldset, form, label, table, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td {
    font-size: 100%;
}

Inherited fromdiv.js-showTitle
html, body, div, span, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre, a, em, img, small, strong, b, u, i, center, ol, ul, li, fieldset, form, label, table, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td {
    font-size: 100%;
}

Inherited fromdiv.tabContent
html, body, div, span, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre, a, em, img, small, strong, b, u, i, center, ol, ul, li, fieldset, form, label, table, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td {
    font-size: 100%;
}

Inherited fromdiv.tabContentWrap
html, body, div, span, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre, a, em, img, small, strong, b, u, i, center, ol, ul, li, fieldset, form, label, table, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td {
    font-size: 100%;
}

Inherited fromdiv.
html, body, div, span, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre, a, em, img, small, strong, b, u, i, center, ol, ul, li, fieldset, form, label, table, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td {
    font-size: 100%;
}

Inherited fromdiv.content
html, body, div, span, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre, a, em, img, small, strong, b, u, i, center, ol, ul, li, fieldset, form, label, table, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td {
    font-size: 100%;
}

Inherited fromdiv.stage
html, body, div, span, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre, a, em, img, small, strong, b, u, i, center, ol, ul, li, fieldset, form, label, table, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td {
    font-size: 100%;
}

Inherited fromdiv.page
html, body, div, span, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre, a, em, img, small, strong, b, u, i, center, ol, ul, li, fieldset, form, label, table, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td {
    font-size: 100%;
}

Inherited fromform#frmHomePage merchandizer.aspx
html, body, div, span, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre, a, em, img, small, strong, b, u, i, center, ol, ul, li, fieldset, form, label, table, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td {
    font-size: 100%;
}

Inherited frombody.body_Merchandizer
body {
    font-family: Arial,san-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
    line-height: 18px;
}

body {
    color: #000000;
    font-family: Arial,san-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
    line-height: 18px;
}

html, body, div, span, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre, a, em, img, small, strong, b, u, i, center, ol, ul, li, fieldset, form, label, table, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td {
    font-size: 100%;
}

Inherited fromhtml
html, body, div, span, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre, a, em, img, small, strong, b, u, i, center, ol, ul, li, fieldset, form, label, table, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td {
    font-size: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Can you post the CSS as text please? I find it hard to read.

Comment: If you supplied the CSS we can figure out.

Comment: Hi, have you scroll all the way down in Firebug (right panel - syle) in order to see where this black color is inherited from?

Comment: Vlad, i have added the css as well. please advise.

Comment: Vlad, i have scrolled all the way still cannot find any property for black color

Comment: Could you try removing the HTML element in question? Is it still black? When you click the “Computed” tab in Firefox, what’s the value given for the `background` properties?

Comment: This is what i see in computed tab   "background-color transparent"

Comment: That is your answer. The background-color is transparent and so is showing through to an element underneath that is black. Step up the DOM tree to find that element, and you will know what is causing it. Why not just overwrite the background color by adding your own?

Comment: @amit as others advised: The easiest solution is to set this element to have `background-color: #fff` (or any particular color). However, if you want to be sure, what is causing your black background, you need to look in your whole CSS code and also to take into account default values of your browser (though I cannot recall, which of browsers have black background as default for such element)

Comment: finally i have found the css element. thanks all for throwing pointers. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Hard to do anything but guess without seeing all the css and html, but there's a good chance that you didn't apply a background to the element, and one of the parent element's background-color is showing.

There are no background declarations in the css you posted, so it's possible this is why. I imagine posting your entire (relevant) code or linking to a demo would get you more accurate answers.